# ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem Causes App to Hang Until Finished

Tags: c#, asp.net, multithreading, threadpool

This may be due to a lack of understanding of what's going on under the hood or simply a lack of understanding of threading in general. When a user logins I need to run some tasks that call web services to update data in my system. Since the services could take a considerable amount of time I thread the entire process. However, even though I think I'm running the whole series of tasks in a thread separate from my application, my application waits until the called function is finished before it proceeds.

```
WindowsIdentity identity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
Manager manager = (Manager)Session["Manager"];

ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new SafeWaitCallback().Call(identity, delegate(object noCallBack)
{
    manager.RunAccountUpdater(identity);
}));
```

The application hangs until the function "RunAccountUpdater" is finished and the callback occurs. What am I doing wrong/not understanding?

Comment: Do you have any related thread-sync code here? Join? Lock? Mutex? Anything similar to Control.Invoke? Anything else that might block?

Comment: `new SafeWaitCallback().Call` runs synchronously. Only its result (which I assume is a WaitCallback) will be scheduled on the ThreadPool. Are you sure it's `manager.RunAccountUpdater` and not `new SafeWaitCallback().Call` that blocks your application? Can you add the full code of the `SafeWaitCallback` class? (You seem to have modified it compared to [this](http://flimflan.com/blog/SafelyRunningBackgroundThreadsInASPNET20.aspx) ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go through you actually do there statement by statement - it will be obviouss.

> ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(new
>   SafeWaitCallback().Call(identity,
>   delegate(object noCallBack)  { 
>       manager.RunAccountUpdater(identity); 
>   }));

This happens from inside out.

- You declare a delegate.
- You then use SafeWaitCallback().Call to EXECUTE the operation.
- Then you queue the result of the Call to.... the thread pool.

Voila - here is your issue. You have to queue the call to the delegte, not the result of the execution.